# Render differences between "Render Image" and "Render Animation" in EEVEE

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

When rendering an animation as image sequence (Render>Render Animation) I am getting different results compared to when its rendered as a single image (Render>Render Image).

These are the same frame of the animation. Nothing changed in settings or setup between them aside from one is taken from the animation image sequence - the other by setting the timeline to the same frame and rendering it as a single image.

The animation is missing the refractions from the background. This is from a texture on the 'world' environment.

The animation frames are faster to render and obviously by default blender is ignoring something.

Is there a setting or box I need to tick to get the animation to recognise the scene the way the individual image does? Its driving me round the bend.

Single Image
[image]

Frame from animation
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that might be interested, the issue was with the world texture.

I was using an mp4 movie as the texture, and while that works great on a plane in the scene in an animation, the world texture wasnt updating each frame.

When i rendered an individual image of any particular frame in the timeline i think blender had the chance to calculate which frame of the movie should be displayed in the world texture, but when i rendered out the animation it got stuck on frame 1 and didnt change.

The solution was to manually keyframe the "offset" value in the texture node to keep pace with the frame of the timeline. Bit of a rough fix but it works.

[image: keyframe offset in world texture]